# Terraform - Combining lists

Tags: terraform

I want to set the ipv4_address on `n` [vsphere_virtual_machine](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine#virtual-machine-customizations) resources using `clone.customize.network_interface.ipv4_address`. It works perfectly when having either an input variable providing `n` addresses or using the netbox `netbox_available_ip_address` resource with count of `n`.

But how can I combine both approaches: I only want to use the `netbox_available_ip_address` ressource if the address list contains an empty string.

VMs variable values:

```
vms = [
    {ipv4_address = "192.168.100.1"},
    {ipv4_address = ""},
    {ipv4_address = "192.168.100.2"},
    {ipv4_address = ""}
 ]
```

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vms" {
  count            = length(var.vms)
  ...
  clone {
  ...
    customize {
      ...
      network_interface {
        ipv4_address = var.vms[count.index].ipv4_address == "" ? split("/", netbox_available_ip_address.ip_available[count.index].ip_address)[0] : var.vms[count.index].ipv4_address
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "netbox_available_ip_address" "ip_available" {
  prefix_id   = data.netbox_prefix.netbox_prefix.id
  count       = sum(concat([for v in var.vms : 1 if v.ipv4_address == ""], [0]))   # get an address only for empty string
}
```

```
Error: Invalid index
ipv4_address = var.vms[count.index].ipv4_address == "" ? split("/", netbox_available_ip_address.ip_available[count.index].ip_address)[0] : var.vms[count.index].ipv4_address

count.index is 3
netbox_available_ip_address.ip_available is tuple with 2 elements
 
The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Comment: Can you add the terraform code for the resource?

Comment: @MarkoE Added TF code

Comment: Wait, is the `ips` variable used anywhere? It's hard to guess what happens without the values of `vms` variable. Can you add that as well?

Comment: Added variable @MarkoE